# How can I add button to the widget area of wordpress to share the current page on social media?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have a code written as below in the custom widget area of WordPress website I set up to display share buttons for different social media. But I would like these buttons to share the current page that the visitor is looking at. How could make this possible?? Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you for your time!

```html
<div class="wpb_wrapper footer_snsShare pc hide-on-single-post">
    <h2 class="p1" style="text-align: center;"><span class="s1"><b>SNS</b></span><b>でシェア！</b></h2>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://tintroom.jp/" target="_blank"
                class="qbutton  left white default btn_snsShare btn_fb" style="color: #333333; font-size: 32px; "
                rel="noopener noreferrer">FACEBOOK<span aria-hidden="true"
                    class="qode_icon_font_elegant social_facebook_circle qode_button_icon_element"
                    style="color: #1877f2;"></span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="http://twitter.com/share?url=https://tintroom.jp/" target="_blank"
                class="qbutton  left white default btn_snsShare btn_twitter"
                style="color: #333333; font-size: 32px; " rel="noopener noreferrer">Twitter<span aria-hidden="true"
                    class="qode_icon_font_elegant social_twitter_circle qode_button_icon_element"
                    style="color: #1da1f2;"></span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="http://line.me/R/msg/text/?https://tintroom.jp/" target="_blank"
                class="qbutton  left white default btn_snsShare btn_line" style="color: #333333; font-size: 34px; "
                rel="noopener noreferrer">LINE<span aria-hidden="true"
                    class="qode-icon-kiko kikos kiko-line qode_button_icon_element"
                    style="color: #00b900;"></span></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use some javascript-code to add the current url to all your share-links.
Like this:

```
<div class="wpb_wrapper footer_snsShare pc hide-on-single-post">
    <h2 class="p1" style="text-align: center;"><span class="s1"><b>SNS</b></span><b>でシェア！</b></h2>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=" target="_blank"
                class="qbutton  left white default btn_snsShare btn_fb" style="color: #333333; font-size: 32px; "
                rel="noopener noreferrer">FACEBOOK<span aria-hidden="true"
                    class="qode_icon_font_elegant social_facebook_circle qode_button_icon_element"
                    style="color: #1877f2;"></span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="http://twitter.com/share?url=" target="_blank"
                class="qbutton  left white default btn_snsShare btn_twitter"
                style="color: #333333; font-size: 32px; " rel="noopener noreferrer">Twitter<span aria-hidden="true"
                    class="qode_icon_font_elegant social_twitter_circle qode_button_icon_element"
                    style="color: #1da1f2;"></span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="http://line.me/R/msg/text/?" target="_blank"
                class="qbutton  left white default btn_snsShare btn_line" style="color: #333333; font-size: 34px; "
                rel="noopener noreferrer">LINE<span aria-hidden="true"
                    class="qode-icon-kiko kikos kiko-line qode_button_icon_element"
                    style="color: #00b900;"></span></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div> 
<script>
  var links = document.getElementsByClassName("btn_snsShare");
  var curUrl = window.location.href;
  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++){
    var href= links[i].getAttribute("href");
    links[i].setAttribute("href",href + curUrl);
  }
</script>
```